# How to calculate minimum positive solution of a equation?

Tags: equation-solving

Equations with triangular function usually have multiple solutions, like `Solve[Sin[x] == 1/10, x]` returns a solution like

```
{{x -> ConditionalExpression[
         2*Pi*C[1] + Pi - ArcSin[1/10], 
         Element[C[1], Integers]]}, 
   {x -> ConditionalExpression[
         2*Pi*C[1] + ArcSin[1/10], 
         Element[C[1], Integers]]}}
```

How to determine the minimum positive solution automatically?

Comment: x /. Solve[{Sin[x] == 1/10, 0 <= x <= Pi/2}, x][[1]]

Comment: @BobHanlon It is not a quite general approach for the problem, but it is simple enough for this specific problem.

Comment: Whatever problem you are working on you should always include known or obvious constraints. This will generally simplify what needs to be done.

Comment: @BobHanlon This is a good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sol = (x /. Solve[Sin[x] == 1/10, x]);
sol2 = Minimize[{#, (# > 0)}, C[1], Integers] & /@ sol
```

> ```
> {{Pi - ArcSin[1/10], {C[1] -> 0}}, {ArcSin[1/10], {C[1] -> 0}}}
> ```

```
Min[sol2[[All, 1]]]
```

> ```
> ArcSin[1/10]
> ```